# Using For /R to delete files from subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is a really beginners question. I have never work with scripts before and today I decided to start learning because of some unknown reason upgrading to Windows 10 duplicated many of my files. There is a pattern for music files, duplicates end in -1,-2,-3... and so on. I created a script with the following and it did work to delete duplicated files.

```
del E:\folder_name\*-1.mp3
del E:\folder_name\*-2.mp3
del E:\folder_name\*-3.mp3
```

However, there are too many folders and specifying one by one will take me forever. I found this script to recursively loop through subdirectories.

```
For /R E:\music_sample\ %%G IN (*-1.mp3) do Echo del "%%G"
```

Which produces the following output

[image]

but it does not actually deletes the files. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the term "Echo" from your script:

```
For /R E:\music_sample\ %%G IN (*-1.mp3) do del "%%G"
```

Comment: That made it! Thank youuuuu :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a moment to learn something new is always great!

Sometimes there is already a tool for the job.

[Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) allows you to search by patterns/regular expressions for files.  This or something similar might save you some time in the future.

Comment: They should teach more of this useful things at my local college! It is awesome the power you can give to a script. Thank you, I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
del /s "%userprofile%\music\*-1.mp3" "%userprofile%\music\*-2.mp3 "%userprofile%\music\*-3.mp3"
```

type

```
set u
```

and

```
del /?
```

for help.

Command prompt has it's own regular expressions. It's different to dos even if the tokens are the same. EG in dos `*` is only valid at the end of a filename or extension but in command prompt it is valid anywhere.